# Adding mailboxes to my domain for notification purposes?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange, shared-mailbox

I currently pay $5/mo for `Office 365 Business Essentials` and I have one email account under my domain (ie. `john@mycompany.com`). I need to create a 2nd email address, whose only purpose is to send me (`john@mycompany.com`) a notification that someone has paid for our app. In other words, when someone pays for the app, `no-reply@mycompany.com` will send `john@mycompany.com` an email notification. That's it.

From my understanding, if I want to create a 2nd email address with my domain, I need to pay Microsoft an additional $5/month. I don't want to pay $5/month for an email that will send me an email about 3-5 times per month and *possibly* receive an email once every three months.

My question: 
1) With `Office 365 Business Essentials`, does it make sense that a 2nd email address with its own password will cost an additional $5/month?

2) I don't mind using my current email address to send these emails to myself. The problem is that it has to have a different password. Can I create a mailbox alias or a shared mailbox with a different password? Or maybe I can use my email address but somehow use a different password for this purpose?

What other options do I have? I want to continue using `Office 365 Business Essentials`, but I don't want to pay another $5. Eventually, I'll need to add two more emails, which means $20/month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a password for shared mailboxes in office 365 by going to the following section in Admin Center:

[Admin Center](https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal) `-> Users -> Active Users`

If you are using the new GUI:

Locate the name of the shared mailbox you have just created, then click on the picture of the key just under the name of the mailbox in the side panel that appears.

If you are using the old GUI:

Same as above but the panel on the right will have a "Reset Password" button.

To further add to this, after creating the shared mailbox I would suggest creating a mail flow rule using the conditions `The recipient is...` which will be the `no-reply@mycompany.com` email address and add a second condition of `The subject or body includes...` and insert a string/phrase that matches content of the email you would like forwarding and then set `Do the following...` to `Bcc the message to...` the `john@mycompany.com` email address.

Mail flow rules are located in this section of office 365:

[Exchange admin center](https://outlook.office365.com/ecp/) `-> Mail Flow -> Rules`

This will bcc the emails to your account that are relevant based on the information that you specify in the subject/body of the email whilst retaining the email in the shared mailbox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to log on using Outlook and was also able to send an email with C# code.

Comment: What's the difference between this new email address and the one I always use? The new one says "Unlicensed" while my regular email address says "Microsoft Flow Free, Office 365 Business Essentials". In both I can log on and send/receive emails.